# Is it safe to send admin credentials to rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, security

I am getting data from magento2 REST api. I send admin credentials to get the token then I use the token to get the data and everything is working fine.

Is it a safe way to do that? Should I create another user with specific permissions for accessing REST api on magento? What is the recommended way to do it?

I am using the below code:

```
    //Authentication rest API magento2
    $adminUrl='http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $var = 
    $data = array("username" => "username", "password" => 'password');                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                       
    $ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );       
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    $token=  json_decode($token); 
    $ch = curl_init( "http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&fields=items[id,name,sku,price,status]" );

    $curlOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            "Content-type: application/json",
            "Authorization: bearer ".$token
        )
    );

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curlOptions );

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

    return $response;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects here:

1. How safe is the transport?

   in your case, **not safer than a postcard**, because you use HTTP and anybody between your device and the server could inspect every detail of request and response.

   **Solution:**

   1. Add an SSL certificate if you don't have any yet. you can get a free one at https://letsencrypt.org/ - this is also important for the security of your customers!
   2. Use `https://example.com` instead of `http://example.com` for your API calls.
2. Should you use a dedicated API user?

   It's generally a good rule of thumb to only allow as much as necessary. So, **yes** you should create one or more separate users for API access that receive just as much permissions as they need.

Comment: I have SSL added on the server, Ican visit the website using HTTPS. When I changed the URL in the above code to use HTTPS, it returned null!! It works on HTTP only. Any Help?

Comment: Maybe the certificate was not accepted. Use [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/curl-error) to see error messages from CURL and find out more.

Comment: I got this error: "error:SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: OK, I would recommend you to replace the self signed certificate with a trusted one (users will get warnings in their browser about an untrusted certificate, that's not good for business). Until then, you can switch off verification, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690173/post-request-with-a-self-signed-certificate (**warning: unsafe!**)

Comment: Is it a server side certificate issue ?? I am sending the request from the localhost to the magento hosted website.

Comment: Yes, it's about the SSL certificate on your Magento server.